# Different ways to create dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I was exploring different ways to create a dictionary in Python 3 (3.11.1). ChatGPT suggested that I can create a dictionary by using the following syntax:

```
my_dict = dict('key1'='value1', 'key2'='value2', 'key3'='value3')
```

[image: Suggestion from ChatGPT]

I tried this in IDLE, but I am getting `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?`.

[image: Error thrown by IDLE]

To confirm if ChatGPT may have suggested the wrong method, I asked the same question with Google Bard. Ever Bard is replying that this method can be used to create a dictionary. Am I missing something?

[image: Google Bard's reply]

Comment: Why did you add quotes? It looks like ChatGPT and Bard are showing the right syntax, but you've added quotes to it, making it invalid.

Comment: BTW, check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: I added quotes because a string is supposed to be in either single or double quotes. Do we have an exception in this particular case?

Comment: They're not strings, they're identifiers (like variable names). You can see a demo in the official tutorial under [Keyword Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments), and for reference: [Calls - Expressions - Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) "keyword_item  ::=  identifier "=" expression". Cf. [Dictionary displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) "dict_item 
 ::=  expression ":" expression".

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea. "They are not strings, they are identifiers" cleared everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey don't give the key1 and key2 and key3 quotes. key names should not be in quotes then it will work

```
my_dict = dict(key1='value1', key2='value2', key3='value3')
print (my_dict)
```

Comment: I was not aware of the syntax. Since it mentioned key1, key2... my assumption was to pass keys. But @wjandrea pointed out that they are actually identifiers, not keys